# PHP, htaccess: Multiple script executing when use "RewriteBase /" on vhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's have a index.php containing code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'][] = 'bar';
print_r($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Normaly it adds one tab index for 1 refresh like this:

start page: `Array ( [0] => bar )`

first refresh: `Array ( [0] => bar [1] => bar )`

second: `Array ( [0] => bar [1] => bar [2] => bar )` (...)

But when I use htaccess rewriting with base: `RewriteBase /` it looks like the script is executed twice for 1 refresh.

The output is like:

start page: `Array ( [0] => bar )`

first refresh: `Array ( [0] => bar [1] => bar [2] => bar )`

second: `Array ( [0] => bar [1] => bar [2] => bar [3] => bar [4] => bar )` (...)

Why is this happening and how to prevent this behavior?

Complete .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
//empty row
```

UPDATE:

I just checked that when i run script on localhost/folder it works correctly.
The sitouation i descriped above happens on virtual host..

And on Firefox it outputs (vhost):

start page: `Array ( [0] => bar )`

first refresh: `Array ( [0] => bar [1] => bar [2] => bar [3] => bar )`

after that each refresh = 1 new index in table.. confusing

Answer (score 2):

**First remark**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This part of your code will **never** be executed since previous block rewrites everything to index file (except for existing files/folders/symlinks). You must put it **before** your first block.

**Second remark**
Since you have a double call to your index, i suspect a `favicon` issue. Basically, when you try to visit a page, a lot of browser will make a parallel http request to `http://website.com/favicon.ico` in order to display an icon associated to the website you're visiting. And i bet you don't have such a file, that's why it is rewritten to `index.php` (because the file does not exist). Yeah, i know... this is totally crappy, especially when you never heard about it.

Well, now you know everything, you can have a workaround:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect "www" to "without-www" equivalent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Don't touch existing files/folders/symlinks or a "favicon.ico" request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon\.ico$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite every other url to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```